# Parse PFTableViewController vs regular UITableView with PFObject as data source

Tags: uitableview, parse-platform

I am new to iOS development, and I have been doing a fair amount of research. Unfortunately, as the title of my post suggests, neither possibility seems exactly suited to my needs.

I need a lot of customization with respect to the look and feel of each individual table view cell, and I need for my table to have header sections which are clickable. I would actually like for the section headers to have the drill down quality and not the cells beneath each section header.

To my knowledge, the problem with PFTableViewController is that it doesn't easily allow for multiple sections (even less so if I need for these section headers to be clickable and of a different look and feel from the regular cells.) Furthermore, customizing the PFTableViewCells doesn't seem terribly simple either.

However, if I use the regular UITableView even with Parse as my backend, won't I run into some  difficulties with respect to loading, pagination, etc...?

I have a pretty good idea of how I would implement this app with regular UITableViews so I guess here is my question: **is it worth it for me to try and figure out all of this PFTableViewController stuff?**

I should also mention the fact that my table view controller will not take up the entire view but only half of the screen.

Thanks in advance for any and all advice

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a normal UITableView will suit your needs. If you want to customize the look and feel of individual cells, you can just subclass a UITableViewCell and modify it.

In terms of your needs with the headers, it's hard to say without knowing more about your app, but you want to follow standard user interface conventions. Users don't expect headers to be clickable. Instead, they attempt to traverse information hierarchies by selecting table view cells, which then bring them to new views with more information. Based on your, needs I think that a standard table view controller with some customization is what you want.